# Preorder tree traversal works but postorder doesn't

Tags: c, tree, segmentation-fault, tree-traversal

I have two functions that traverse a tree in `preorder` and `postorder`, each inserting the values in the nodes into an array, and returning the array.

However, my `postorder` function does not work. I get a segmentation fault when the function is called.

When the following code is compiled and run, but after calling the `postorder` method I get a segmentation fault.

This is my code:

```
int* preorder_recursive(node *root, int* dataArray)
{

  if (root == NULL)
    return dataArray;

  for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
  {
    if (dataArray[i] == INT_MIN)
    {
      dataArray[i] = root->data;
      printf("%d is being inserted to the preorder array at pos %d\n", root->data, i);
      break;
    }
  }

  preorder_recursive(root->left, dataArray);
  preorder_recursive(root->right, dataArray);
}

int* postorder_recursive(node *root, int *dataArray)
{
  if (root == NULL)
    return dataArray;

  postorder_recursive(root->left, dataArray);

  postorder_recursive(root->right, dataArray);

  for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
  {
    // any "empty" spots in the array should contain INT_MIN
    if (dataArray[i] == INT_MIN)
    {
      dataArray[i] = root->data;
      printf("%d is being inserted to the postorder array at pos %d\n", root->data, i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

When calling:

```
int * complete_pre_b = preorder_recursive(b, pre_order_b);
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("pre b is %d\n", complete_pre_b[i]);
}

int * complete_post_b = postorder_recursive(b, post_order_b);
// here is the last print I see - code get till here fine
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    printf("post b is %d\n", complete_post_b[i]);
}
```

(**Notice** - I have tree with 3 node that why I loop for i from 0 to 3)

What can be the issue? What is the different between my post and pre order?

Comment: It appears fine from an algorithmic perspective. It's high time for a minimal, complete and laconic example I think . . .

Comment: Can you please post the use case that fails and the main? (creating the dataArray and the function usage)
Does the segmentation fault happens at the begin of the function or in the middle? do you get any prints at all?

Comment: I have edited the post to include all of my code @DavidWinder

Comment: @gsamaras I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: And that's why you got yourself an answer, good, nice question now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you do: `complete_post_b = postorder_recursive(b, post_order_b);` when `complete_post_b` is define at the begin of `main` as: `int* complete_post_b;`

However, at the `postorder_recursive` you **do not** returning any data. so when assiging to `complete_post_b` it actually void.

Your for loop should be as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   printf("post b is %d\n", post_order_b[i]); // and not complete_post_b 
}
```

Or you can return the `dataArray` and use the `complete_post_b`.

For the interest part: **why does it happens only on postOrder**?

Notice, that the only time you return the `dataArray` is when the node is null. My guess is in that case, the register for return value will contain the data array. When having the recursive function call at the end of your function the address of the data array stays in the register and transfer forward - but you can not count on that and you need to actually return the address if you want to use it

Comment: How should I modify my code to return the address, without breaking everything?

Comment: @Uclydde you can just add `return dataArray` at the end of the function - but I believe better will be to modify the function to void and use the original array in the main

Comment: Adding the return statement did the trick! Thank you so much!